# Is there a way to bypass problem of package split in java automatic modules when we're not in charge of included code

Tags: java, maven, java-module, druid

I have a custom library for creating requests to Apache Druid database which I would like to turn into java modules.

My library includes dependencies:

- org.apache.druid:druid-processing:0.22.1
- org.apache.druid:druid-core:0.22.1

which are then converted to automatic modules (as they do not have module-info.java)

As it is described here https://jenkov.com/tutorials/java/modules.html , when more automatic modules are added, all read all packages from other auto modules to check if there is no package split problem.

In case of those libraries there are several packages named the same, so I get errors like

```
   [ERROR] error: module commons.lang reads package org.apache.druid.guice.annotations from both druid.processing and druid.core
```

also, interesting thing is I get errors stating e.g. druid-core scans its and druid-processing packages

```
[ERROR] error: module druid.core reads package org.apache.druid.segment from both druid.processing and druid.core
```

so **my question is: is ther any way to bypass this problem?**

Those libraries are in github so in the end I could create merge request with some changes, but it is more general question how to bypass this kind of issues for any libraries which we do not control, and has package conflict and we would like to use them in moduled project.

Comment: I think the answer is that only very few people are interested in using Java modules. Most people just go on using Java without the module system.

Comment: Have you tried to merge all druid jar into a single jar and use that as dependency ?

Comment: You can't really bypass that because it's needs to be fixed on the library side otherwise it will not really work...

Comment: @HervéGuillemet ok this was one of my ideas. I see I should use maven assembly. Then probably I should release such jar (or module) into my artifactory with some version and use. Could do the trick but it's applicable only when we have access to sources (which is the case here, but I also wonder for general solution)

Comment: @JFabianMeier this is also my impression... I realized if only 2 libraries in your dependencies has this problem, then modular approach fails across whole project (this druid library becomes dependency of several microservices)